# ReactJS - TypeError: Cannot set property 'propOne' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple React component:

```
import React from "react";

export default class Car extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h2>I am a {this.props.name}</h2>;
  }
}
```

I am then importing this component into another component. This new component has a textbox which onChange event, tries to set a property which is being passed as a property to component one.

```
import React from "react";
import Car from "./Car";

class Garage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.propOne = "Ford";
    this.state = { value: "initial Value" };
  }

  handleChange(event) {

    this.propOne = event.target.value;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.state.value}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <Car name={this.propOne} />
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Garage;
```

After running this  code, **I am getting TypeError: Cannot set property 'propOne' of undefined** error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referenced error is thrown because you didn't bind `this`.

Other than that, you have a bunch of errors in your code, so I tried to address them all at once. If you have further questions, feel free to ask in the comments:

```js
const { render } = ReactDOM

class Car extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h2>I am a {this.props.name}</h2>
  }
}

class Garage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.state = { value: "initial Value", propOne: 'Ford' }
  }

  handleChange(val) {
    this.setState({value: val, propOne: val})
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.state.value}
          onChange={e => this.handleChange(e.target.value)}
        />
        <Car name={this.state.propOne} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

render(
  <Garage />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```

p.s. and I agree with above answers, function components and hooks could make your app look much nicer

Answer (score 3):

It's because you are making a new function and creating a new instance of `this`. Change it to an arrow function -

```
 handleChange = (event) => {

    this.propOne = event.target.value;
  }
```

Or you can bind the `this` of `handleChange` to parent's `this` in the constructor of class

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.propOne = "Ford";
    this.state = { value: "initial Value" };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
```

Comment: this works but I am still not able to pass new value (set during onChange event) to `car` component. voting up for fixing the error.

Comment: @OpenStack, likely you _can_ update the prop, but the component isn't being re-rendered as it is not done via `setState`

Answer (score 1):

Kudos to @Atin for mentioning changing your `handleChange` function to an arrow function or binding `this` (I'll use the arrow function in my answer).

You'll also need to set `propOne` in state, and use `this.setState(...)` to update the value of `propOne` so that your component re-renders when `propOne` changes. When you just change `this.propOne`, React doesn't know that your component needs to re-render with the updated value, which is why you don't see the effect in `Car`. -> that's what the `state` is for. Whenever `state` is changed (with `this.setState`), React knows it needs to re-render that component, and it will pass your updated state property down to child components.

Try this for your `state`:

```
this.state = { value: "initial Value", propOne: "Ford" };
```

And this for your `handleChange` function:

```
handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ propOne: event.target.value });
}
```

**Edit**:

Additionally, your code (and the above, fixed code) is setting a property `propOne` on the state, but you're using `this.state.value` to update your `input` text value. Is there any reason you're trying to use two different properties - `value` and `propOne`? It seems they're being used for the same purpose, and therefore you can replace `propOne` with `value` everywhere like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: "initial Value" };
}

handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
}

render() {
    return (
        <>
            <input
                type="text"
                value={this.state.value}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            <Car name={this.state.value} />
        </>
    );
}
```